# How to have a tree view automatically populated when different .mdb files are loaded in c#?

Tags: c#, treeview, oledb

I am currently working on a project, it is a c# winform app that can open any .mdb file read and display the records and make changes to it and save the changes again. For this I am using OLEDb libraries.

Now my question is, I would like a tree view to be populated with the data from the the .mdb file that I have opened.

Is this possible?

My Google searches have only shown me examples of creating a tree view using a single .mdb file, but not have the ability to adapt to different .mdb files.

Please, any answer or indication to a possible answer will mean a lot to me.

I thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, possible. So what have you tried?

Comment: If it is possible with one .mdb file don't you think it will be possible with multiepl .mdb files? What did you try so far?

Comment: I have been able to manually set the nodes to the table names etc.. but I manually types the name in for example "name", "location", I need the app to automatically be able to fill the tree view with any database thrown at it.